# sqlcommand for updation

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

I have a table which I want to update using a simple update command.

```
protected void UpdateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE KPI_DETAILS_TABLE SET KPI1_Status =
         @KPI1_Status, KPI2_Status = @KPI2_Status, KPI3_Status = @KPI3_Status,
         KPI4_Status = @KPI4_Status, KPI5_Status = @KPI5_Status, KPI6_Status =
         @KPI6_Status, Overall_Status= @Overall_Status WHERE TokenID = '" + 
         DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text + "' AND TimeSet = '" 
         + currentdate + "'", connection);

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@KPI1_Status", DropboxKPI1.SelectedItem.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@KPI2_Status", DropboxKPI2.SelectedItem.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@KPI3_Status", DropboxKPI3.SelectedItem.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@KPI4_Status", DropboxKPI4.SelectedItem.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@KPI5_Status", DropboxKPI5.SelectedItem.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@KPI6_Status", DropboxKPI6.SelectedItem.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Overall_Status", FinalStatus.SelectedItem.Text);

        try
        {
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            Error1.Text = "KPI Status Successfully Updated !!";
        }
        catch { Error1.Text = "Error during Updating status of KPIs"; }
        finally { connection.Close(); }
    }
```

However it's throwing the following exception error:

> The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

The only column of datatype `datetime` in the database is `TimeSet`. But `currentdate` is also of data type `datetime`.

```
DateTime currentdate = DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime();
```

Then why is this error popping up? Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should look like this:

```
    protected void UpdateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE KPI_DETAILS_TABLE SET"+
        "KPI1_Status = @KPI1_Status, KPI2_Status = @KPI2_Status,"+
        "KPI3_Status = @KPI3_Status, KPI4_Status = @KPI4_Status,"+
        "KPI5_Status = @KPI5_Status, KPI6_Status = @KPI6_Status,"+
        "Overall_Status= @Overall_Status"+
        "WHERE TokenID = @ID AND TimeSet = @Time", connection);

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@KPI1_Status", DropboxKPI1.SelectedItem.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@KPI2_Status", DropboxKPI2.SelectedItem.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@KPI3_Status", DropboxKPI3.SelectedItem.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@KPI4_Status", DropboxKPI4.SelectedItem.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@KPI5_Status", DropboxKPI5.SelectedItem.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@KPI6_Status", DropboxKPI6.SelectedItem.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Overall_Status", FinalStatus.SelectedItem.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Time", DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime());
    try
    {
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        Error1.Text = "KPI Status Successfully Updated !!";
    }
    catch { Error1.Text = "Error during Updating status of KPIs"; }
    finally { connection.Close(); }
}
```

1. Repaired the mess in the string of your `SqlCommand` object.
2. Instead of adding local variables to your `SqlCommand` I added new `SqlParameters` and defined where they'd get their values from (@ID, @Time).

Answer (score 2):

a) Use parameters for the values in your `WHERE` clause, as well as for the `SET` part, and

b) Then use `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TimeSet", DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime());`

This will also protect you from SQL injection.

---

I.e. if you've got a datetime value, try to keep it as a datetime value, and don't muck about with trying to treat it as a string at any point. Let ADO.Net and SQL Server deal with any necessary conversions.

Comment: i got what u said. thanks for the valuable advice.
but i had the use this value of datetime.now.localtime() somewhere else as well. so couldnt use the method directly over here.

Comment: can u explain how ur method can protect the app from sql injection?

Comment: "If you post data access code to the forums as part of a question, and people reply with "Watch out for SQL Injection!", or "Use parameter queries!", you may wonder why they seem so concerned..."

http://forums.asp.net/p/1568268/3920715.aspx ..check this post for more information about Sql Injection and parametrized quires

Answer (score 0):

Instead you use `DateTime.Now.ToString();` for giving the Currentdate and try again.